# How do I list all nodes created by user specified in argument using Views in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views

I have been trying to create a page using views that will list down all the nodes authored by a specific user.
The user name will be specified in the path (like - stuff/[user-name] )

Can someone please tell me how to do this using Views.
I am stuck on a dead end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the views url path specify: stuff/%
in the arguments section add: user -> user: name

Should do it, but I'm not sure if it isn't buggy (see this issue: http://drupal.org/node/744468)

If you use user:id instead of username, you will be fine.

Comment: yeah, I actually did all that. Used user : name ->leads to the query being built with uid, so shouldn't really make a difference (?)
How do I filter the results to match the node author's uid to the argument?